# Adding a fade to background image transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Seems everything I found on here proposed something far more complicated than it might need to be.

I basically just want this to fadeIn("slow") on changeBackground...
Any suggestions for easy implementation?

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var images = [ "bg1.jpg", "bg2.jpg", "bg3.jpg", "bg4.jpg" ];
    var currentImage = 0;

    function changeBackground() {
        $( '#home' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')' } );
        if ( currentImage >= images.length - 1 ) {
            currentImage -= images.length;
        }
    }

    setInterval( changeBackground, 2600 );  
});
```

Comment: I've never found a solution. I always make a function that fades in an image on top of my BG image, and once it fades in all the way, change the BG image. Then set the top image back to an opacity of 0. Repeat for each change. I think chrome only support background image transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version (wrapper, slide) versus the wrapper, slide, slide method:

Code:

```
<script>
var images = [ "bg1.jpg", "bg2.jpg", "bg3.jpg", "bg4.jpg" ];
var cur_image = 0;

function changeBackground() {

    cur_image++;

    if ( cur_image >= images.length )
        cur_image = 0;

    // change images
    $( '#container' ).css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ cur_image ] + ')'
    });

    $( '#container .slide' ).fadeOut( 'slow', function(){
        $( this ).css({
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ cur_image ] + ')'
        }).show();
    } );

}

setInterval( changeBackground, 2600 );
</script>
```

Here is sample markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>This is example content.</p>
        <p>This is more content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
#container { height: 768px; width: 1024px; background: url(bg2.jpg); }
#container .slide { height: 768px; width: 1024px; position: absolute; }
#container .content { position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px; padding: 1em; background: rgba(255,255,255,.5); }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do this with jQuery and still have a easy implementation, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WRMfU/

The idea is to place the image player with two divs inside, one on top of another like this:

```
<div id="player">
    <div id="player-top"></div>
    <div id="player-bottom" class="img00"></div>
</div>
```

With jQuery, you place an image at the top div `player-top`, set it as hidden, and perform a fadeIn animation, after the animation is done, you place the top image in the bottom div `player-bottom`, so it will be ready for the next time you place a new image in the top and perform the same tasks again.

```
var nImages = 3, currImage = 0;

function changePic(){
    var top = $("#player-top");
    currImage == nImages ? currImage = 0 : currImage++;
    top.hide().addClass("img0"+currImage).fadeIn(800, function(){
        $("#player-bottom").attr("class", top.attr("class"));
        top.attr("class", "");
    });
}

setInterval(changePic, 2000);
```

I'm using CSS to create classes to hold background images, so its easier to deal with that in javascript...

```
#player > div.img00 { background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/400x300/440/ffffff&text=Image+01"); }
#player > div.img01 { background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/400x300/404/ffffff&text=Image+02"); }
...
```